# Hypen(-) in pig column

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to generate a column using `foreach` statement. The column has hyphen(-) in it.

Pig throws the below error, but I would like to have hyphen in my column, because my target sql server table has hyphen.

ex. column name : KPI_Inter-ENB

```
" mismatched input '-' expecting SEMI_COLON"
```

Can anyone pls help me on solving this issue?

Comment: You want to have a hyphen in the name of the field, in your Pig code?

Answer (score 0):

Hyphen is one among the reserved keywords in PIG and hence the error. 
Please see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#Reserved+Keywords

Comment: Thanks Sanju, I understand this but is there any work around to achive my requirement (hyphen in my sql table column)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can work around this designed behaviour. Per my understand you can't.